# Docker-Compose Volume mounting from windows to linux container makes everything executable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im working on some Ansible stuff that I we have setup in a docker container. when run from a linux system it works great. When run from a windows system I get the following error:

```
ERROR! Problem running vault password script /etc/ansible-deployment/secrets/vault-dev.txt ([Errno 8] Exec format error). If this is not a script, remove the executable bit from the file.
```

Basically what this is saying is that the file is marked as an executable. What i've noticed (and hasnt been a huge problem until now) is that all files mounted to a linux container from windows are ALWAYS tagged with the executable attribute.

Is there any way to control/prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `:ro` at the end of the mounted path?

Something like this:

```
HOST:CONTAINER:ro
```

Comment: Just tried that, no luck. I had considered this but had not tried it because i had assumed (rightfully i guess) that write access doesnt really have to do with it being executable, but i feel like there should be a flag similar to this that says dont make it executable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the SMB-based approach that Docker for Windows uses for making host-mounted volumes work, see [here](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/3298#issuecomment-302106793)

To solve the `executable bit` error, I ended up passing Ansible a python script as the --vault-password-file argument as a workaround, see [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vault.html#single-encrypted-variable).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
vault_password = open('PATH_TO_YOUR_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE', 'r')
print vault_password.read()
vault_password.close()
```

Since the python script is executed in the container, the vault password file path needs to be accessible in the container - I'm mounting it as a volume, but you can also build it into your image. The latter is a security risk and is not recommended.